# Show that for every n ≥ 1, the equation x2≡a modpn 1 has a solution.

Tags: number-theory

Let p be an odd prime and let a be an integer not divisible by p. Suppose that a mod p is a quadratic residue.

a) Show that for every n ≥ 1, the equation $x^2 ≡ a \mod p^n$ has a solution. In other words: a is a square in $Z/p^n$ for all n ≥ 1.

b) Show that for each n ≥ 1, there are exactly two solutions to the congruence
$x^2 ≡ a \mod p^n$ in $Z/p^n$. Deduce that for an odd prime p, the only two solutions to $x^2 ≡ 1 \mod p^n$ are $x ≡ ±1 \mod p^n$.

Could anyone guide me through this? I was considering using induction, but am not completely sure how to begin doing so. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is kind of written backwards. Sure, one can solve a) by discovering lifting, but that is not entirely easy.  Maybe more natural is to first show, in the spirit of b), that there at most two solutions, and then use a counting argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as Hensel lifting (which you can google). Once you have a solution $x_0$ mod $p,$ then look for the solution modulo $p^2$ as
$b p + x_0.$ Note that $(bp + x_0)^2 = b^2 p^2 + 2 p bx_0 + x_0^2.$ Since $x_0^2=  k p + a,$ we are looking for $2 p b x_0 + k p \equiv 0 \mod p^2,$ which is equivalent to $2 b x_0 + k \equiv 0 \mod p.$ This is a linear equation. Now, proceed by induction.